# Задача с двумя списками

Tags: python, list, список

**Сразу извиняюсь за очень длинный вопрос, но по другому описать не получается. По-началу задача показалось мне легкой, но по итогу два дня не с места. Всем заранее спасибо за ответы, при любых вопросах, пожалуйста, задавайте их в комментариях, я постараюсь ответить максимально быстро.**

Существует список currentGrid. В нем 24 значения. Эти значения меняются после каждого нажатия левой кнопки мыши. Меняются определенным образом. До первого нажатия список выглядит так:

```
currentGrid = [40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]
```

24 значения, и все равны 40.

После первого клика, первый элемент со значением 40 изменяется, на какое-то случайное число.

```
currentGrid = [77, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]
```

После второго клика, второй элемент со значением 40 изменяется, на какое-то случайное число.Это может быть тоже самое число, а может и нет.

```
currentGrid = [77, 77, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]
```

После третьего клика, первый и второй элемент изменяется обратно на 40, но "открывается" третий элемент.Число также случайно.

```
currentGrid = [40, 40, 56, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]
```

И так далее: каждый четный клик открывается один элемент.

Каждый нечетный клик пропадают два предыдущих элемента и открывается один новый.

"Пропадает" = Значение элемента становится равно 40.

"Появляется" = Значение элемента становится отлично от 40.

Наконец-то к проблеме.

Нужно определенным образом записывать значения из `currentGrid` в другой список, назовем его `saveGrid`. В `saveGrid` значения должны как-бы "сохраняться".

Привожу пример:

Элементы со значением 40 должны игнорироваться.

Первый клик:

```
currentGrid = [77, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]

saveGrid = [77]
```

Второй клик:

```
currentGrid = [77, 92, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]

saveGrid = [77, 92]
```

Третий клик:

```
currentGrid = [40, 40, 67, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]

saveGrid = [77, 92, 67]
```

Четвертый клик :

```
currentGrid = [40, 40, 67, 89, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]

saveGrid = [77, 92, 67, 89]
```

Пятый клик :

```
currentGrid = [40, 40, 40, 40, 11, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]

saveGrid = [77, 92, 67, 89, 11]
```

И так далее.

Также, список должен соблюдать порядок (не перемешивать все местами) , список должен вмещать в себя 24 значения.

**Забыл упомянуть!**

24 значения - это 12 пар.
То есть уникальных чисел 12, но у каждого есть пара, в сумме 24.

Напоминаю цель:

Нужно определенным образом записывать значения из currentGrid в другой список, назовем его saveGrid. В saveGrid значения должны как-бы "сохраняться".

**Основная часть кода:**

```
def getGrid():
 saveGrid = []
 currentGrid = []
 state_left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
 while 1:
    a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
    if a != state_left: 
       state_left = a
       if a == 1 or a == 0 :
          time.sleep(0.3)
          image = ImageGrab.grab()
          for cord in Cords.cordArray:
           r, g, b = image.getpixel(cord)
           currentGrid.append(b)
          print(currentGrid)
          currentGrid.clear()
        
getGrid()
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что добавлять значение во второй список по клику - хорошая идея? Мб лучше сразу создать два списка равной длины, а по клику просто копировать из второго списка в первый на 1 элемент больше, чем в предыдущий раз?

Comment: Эмм, честно не могу визуализировать у себя в голове вашу идею, хотелось бы увидеть коротенький пример, если вас не затруднит.

Comment: Вообще такая система хранения состояния не выглядит оптимальной. Если есть какое-то состояние по-умолчанию (40, как я понял), то, может быть, есть смысл отслеживать только состояния, отличные от него. Например, хранить набор пар "позиция - измененное значение".

Comment: Возможно, просто не до конца понимаю смысл хранить позицию, если абсолютно всегда значения меняются слева направос определенной периодичностью

Comment: Может, вам стоит сформулировать общую задачу, которую решаете.

Comment: Пока мысль не ушла из головы, напишу сюда. Можно чекать currentGrid на наличие элементов отличных от 40. Каждый второй клик. То есть первый раз кликаем открывается один элемент, ничего не записываем. Второй раз кликаем, открывается второй элемент, записываем оба. Третий раз кликаем, те два пропали, открылся третий, ничего не делаем, четвертый раз открылся четвертый, записываем оба, и тд.

Comment: `saveGrid.append(currentGrid[ClickNumber-1])`

Comment: MBo, выглядит так как будто должно работать, только нужно создать функцию которая считает клики... Если есть желание, можете попробовать написать. Я сейчас добавлю в вопрос основную часть кода для понимая.

Comment: Общая задача - из одного списка значения которого постоянно меняются, перенести значения которые постоянно меняются в другой список и больше их не менять

Comment: Пожалуйста, напишите все ваши импорты.

Comment: Перестаньте плодить вопросы об одном и том же! Это уже третий (если не брать те, что очень похожи по смыслу, но код немного отличается) вопрос за вашим авторством про изменение списков, состоящий из значений `40`! Опишите задачу целиком и попросите помощи. Очевидно, вы что-то делаете не так.

Comment: Все импорты : `from PIL import ImageGrab , ImageOps
import pyautogui
import os
import time
import win32api
import numpy as np`

Comment: cauf, очевидно что я не знаю как это сделать, описал задачу довольно подробно, привел много примеров, что значит описать целиком?

Comment: MBo, Есть ли возможность добавить проверку прям в эту строчку `saveGrid.append(currentGrid[ClickNumber-1])` ? Если элемент = 40, не добавлять.

Comment: Можно, но не нужно. Клик "открывает" элемент, и он тут же пишется во второй список. Не нужно запутывать задачу.

Comment: Все работает корректно, но хотелось бы внести маленкую поправку. Сейчас результат выглядит так : `[108]
[108, 109]
[108, 109, 255]
[108, 109, 255, 108]`  После каждого клика строится лесенка. Хотелось бы что-бы пока значение не достигнет 24, ничего не выводилось.

Comment: Количество элементов массива не достигнет 24 *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При открывании элемента он тут же пишется во второй список:

```
saveGrid.append(currentGrid[ClickNumber-1])
```

Чтобы отображалось только финальное состояние `saveGrid`, можно поставить проверку на номер клика или достижение нужной длины

```
if len(saveGrid) == 24:
    печатать
```